# issue to run behat/selenium with browser without closing it immediately

Tags: javascript, selenium, behat

I am trying to run the behat/selenium with Chrome browser by running the following feature scenario, and I want to hold the browser screen without closing the Chrome browser immediately. I keep getting the following error on implementing the step definition iWaitForSeconds but I did it already. Below are all the code, could you please help to see what did I do wrong? Thanks so much!!!!

```
2 scenarios (2 undefined)
10 steps (8 passed, 2 undefined)
0m3.896s

You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

    /**
     * @Given /^I wait for "([^"]*)" seconds$/
     */
    public function iWaitForSeconds($arg1)
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }
```

/behat_sample/features/search.feature

```
# features/search.feature
Feature: Search
  In order to see a word definition
  As a website user
  I need to be able to search for a word

  @javascript
  Scenario: Searching for a page that does exist
    Given I am on "/wiki/Main_Page"
    When I fill in "search" with "Behavior Driven Development"
    And I press "searchButton"
    Then I should see "agile software development"
    And I wait for "60" seconds
```

/behat_sample/behat.yml

```
#behat.yml
default:
  paths:
    features: features
    bootstrap: '/behat_sample/features/bootstrap'
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      base_url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/'
      goutte: ~
      selenium2: ~
      browser_name: chrome
```

/behat_sample/features/bootstrap/FeatureContext.php

```
namespace bootstrap;
    use Behat\Behat\Context\ClosuredContextInterface,
        Behat\Behat\Context\TranslatedContextInterface,
        Behat\Behat\Context\BehatContext,
        Behat\Behat\Exception\PendingException;
    use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode,
        Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;
    use Behat\MinkExtension\Context\MinkContext;

    /**
    * Features context.
    */
    class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
    {
    /**
    * Initializes context.
    * Every scenario gets it's own context object.
    *
    * @param array $parameters context parameters (set them up through behat.yml)
    */
    public function __construct(array $parameters)
    {
        // Initialize your context here

    }
    /**
    * @Given /^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/
    */
    public function iWaitForSeconds($seconds)
    {
         $this->getSession()->wait($seconds*1000);
         throw new PendingException();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you set wrong path in `bootstrap` config key.
It looks for `/behat_sample/features/bootstrap` instead of `your_current_base_behat_dir/features/bootstrap`

Try the following:

`bootstrap: '%paths.base%/features/bootstrap'`
where `%paths.base%` - thats a where behat root located, from where you start running behat

Answer (score 0):

As I see in the code you need to remove the `throw new PendingException()` from `/^I wait for (\d+) seconds$/` step implementation.

If the wait is done then it should continue not to throw exception.